# Neo4j: matching nodes with 2 more properties in common

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with data from a csv file which contains 4 columns of data: `hotelName`, `hotelPool`, `hotelSpa`, `hotelGym`, where `hotelName` is the unique name of the hotel, `hotelPool` lists what kind of pool the hotel has, `hotelSpa` lists what kind of spa the hotel has, and `hotelGym` lists what kind of gym the hotel has.

Sample data as follows:

Row 1 `"California", "Full-size", "Full-size", "Fully-equipped"`

Row 2 `"Yorba", "Full-size", "None", "Full-equipped"`

Row 3 `"Heartbreak", "None", "Full-size", "Full-equipped"`

Row 4 `"Chelsea", "Full-size", "Full-size", "Fully-equipped"`

I want to match these hotels if they share 2 or more features in common.

For example, California has 2 features in common with Yorba - both hotels have full-size pools and fully-equipped gyms.

California also has 2 features in common with Heartbreak - both hotels have full-sized spas and fully equipped gyms.

California also has 3 features in common with Chelsea - both hotels have full-sized pools, full-sized spas, and fully equipped gyms.

My desired output is pairs of hotels that have 2 or more features in common, as follows:

Row 1 `California, Yorba, 2`
Row 2 `California, Heartbreak, 2`
Row 3 `California, Chelsea, 3`

How do I match based on 2 or more features?

Comment: How many columns do you actually have: 4 or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// get all hotels
MATCH (h:Hotel)

// create hotel pairs, avoiding duplicates
WITH COLLECT(h) AS hotels
UNWIND hotels AS h1
UNWIND hotels AS h2
WITH h1,h2 
WHERE id(h1)>id(h2)

//loop through keys and count same values 
WITH h1, h2,
     REDUCE(i=0, key in keys(h1)  |
            i
            + CASE WHEN h1[key] = h2[key] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     )  AS sameCount

// set your limit
WHERE sameCount >=3 

RETURN h1.hotelName, h2.hotelName , sameCount
```